# What is the difference between "Elder is a girl" and "Random child is a girl" problem?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

I'm learning Probability and Statistics for the first time and there is a part where my professor said "it's done the same way, let's skip" but I don't understand how it's done the same way.

The first question goes like this:

> A family has two children, and it is known that at least one is a
>   girl. What is the probability that both are girls, given this
>   information?

For this I understood that the all possible cases of having 2 children are $ \{GG, GB, BG, BB\} $. So when calculating the probability, it would be 
$$ P(both \space girls|at \space least \space one \space girl) = \frac{P(both \space girls \cap at  \space least \space  one \space girl)}{ P(at \space least \space one \space girl)} $$

Since the cases of having at least one girl is $\{GG,GB,BG\}$ so $ P(at \space  least  \space one \space  girl)$ should be $\frac 34 $.
And the cases of $ both \space  girls \cap at \space least \space one  \space girl $ is when all are girls, $\{GG\}$, so $ P(both \space girls \cap at \space least \space one \space girl) $ is $\frac{1}{4}$.

So I put all the values in, $$ P(both \space girls|at \space least \space one \space girl) = \frac{P(both \space girls \cap at  \space least \space  one \space girl)}{ P(at \space least \space one \space girl)} = \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{3}{4}} = \frac{1}{3} $$

So the first question I understood, but when I tried to solve the second question the same way I got confused.

The second question goes like this:

> A family has two children. You run into one of them and she is a girl.
>   What is the probability that both children are girls given this
>   information. Assuming that you are likely to run into either child,
>   and that which one you run into has nothing to do with gender.

I thought that $ P(random \space child\space is \space girl) $ will be $\frac{3}{4}$, as in the first question, because the cases that you randomly meet a girl is $\{GG,GB,GB\}$ out of $ \{GG, GB, BG, BB\} $.

And $P(both \space girls \cap random \space child\space is \space girl)$ would be $\{GG\}$ out of $ \{GG, GB, BG, BB\} $, $\frac{1}{4}$.

So the answer for this question would be (what I thought) was $$ P(both \space girls|random \space child\space is \space girl) = \frac{P(both \space girls \cap random \space child\space is \space girl)}{ P(random \space child\space is \space girl)} = \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{3}{4}} = \frac{1}{3} $$

However, in the book it says that for events $G_1, G_2, G_3$ that elder, younger, and random child is a girl respectively, $P(G_1), P(G_2), P(G_3)$ are all $\frac{1}{2}$.

For $P(G_1), P(G_2)$ I understand because it would be cases of $\{GG,GB\}$ and $\{GG,BG\}$ out of $ \{GG, GB, BG, BB\} $.

But shouldn't it be $\frac{3}{4}$ for $P(G_3)$ because the possible cases are $ \{GG, GB, BG\} $ out of $ \{GG, GB, BG, BB\} $?

Sorry for the long question and bad formatting (it's my first time). But I really don't understand how this is supposed to work. What makes the two questions different that the answers are different? I must be thinking in some wrong way... Could you please help? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: there is a long and detailed [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox) about this interesting problem, the usual interpretation (Graham Kemp's answer), the variants, and (IMHO the best part) the disagreements / arguments.  :)  make sure you read the part about the girl being born on a tuesday -- it affects the probability!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But shouldn't it be $\tfrac 34$ for $P(G3)$ because the possible cases are $\{GG,GB,BG\}$ out of $\{GG,GB,BG,BB\}$?

$G_3$ is the event that you meet a random child of the family, and that one is a girl.

So the outcomes are described by family-type and which-child.   Of the **eight** equiprobable outcomes, four result in meeting a girl. $$\rm \{\underline{GG1}, \underline{GG2}, \underline{GB1}, GB2, BG1, \underline{BG2}, BB1, BB2\} $$

So, of the *four* equiprobable outcomes where you meet a girl, *two* belong to a family with two girls.  You might have met the younger or older sibling with equal probability, but whichever it was, the probability that the other child is a girl is $1/2$.

---

Notice how you do not meet a girl in two outcomes where the family does have exactly one girl, *but* you meet her sibling.

This highlights the difference in information given by the statements "*at least* one is a girl", and "*this* one is a girl"

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Just to double check, in the first question, it was random; there's no need to care about the order. But the second question adds in the feature of 'older/younger sibling' (by actually meeting the girl), so the cases we have to consider expands with 'which older/younger girl/boy' we met? And the 1, 2 in the outcomes {} stands for older/younger sibling that I met?

Comment: Basically, yes, that is it. @user11618913

Comment: Alternatively, you do not have to order the children by *age*.  You *may* order them by *any* distinguishing trait; such by whether you meet them or not.  Then the equiprobable outcomes would be $\sf\{GG, GB, BG, BB\}$ and the first two outcomes are where you meet a girl.